# Is there any way instead of status_code to determine the request is true or false?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python3 with **BeautifulSoup**. I want to scrape data for a few *employees* from a site, depending on their `ID number`.

My code:

```py
for UID in range(201810000,201810020):
    ID = UID
    print(ID)
    #scrapped Data 
    ZeroDay = s.post("https://site/Add_StudantRow.php",data={"SID":ID})
    ZeroDay_content = bs(ZeroDay.content,"html.parser", from_encoding='windows-1256')
    std_ID    = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"SID[]"})["value"]
    std_name  = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"Name[]"})["value"]
    std_major_= ZeroDay_content.select_one("option[selected]", {"name":"Qualifications[]"})["value"]
    std_major = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"Specialization[]"})["value"]
    std_social= ZeroDay_content.select_one("select[name='MILITARY_STATUS[]'] option[selected]")["value"]
    std_ID_num= ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"ID_Number[]"})["value"]
    std_gender= ZeroDay_content.select_one("select[name='Gender[]'] option[selected]")["value"]

print(std_ID,std_name,std_gender,std_major,std_major_,std_ID_num,std_social)
```

After I ran my code, this error appeared:

```py
    std_ID    = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"SID[]"})["value"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I assigned a range for their *ID*'s from `201810000` to `201810020` but not all the IDs are valid. I mean maybe `201810015` not valid and `201810018` valid.

Note: when I put a valid ID in `UID` the error did not appear, possibly because when the `ID` returns a *null* value the error appears, but how can I do a range of `ID`s in this case?

Comment: try except block and test if none

Answer (score 1):

As not all of your UID values return a valid page, you would just need to first test for the presence of a required tag. As you are looking for form elements, I assume there will be an enclosing `<form>` tag you could test for first.

For example:

```py
for UID in range(201810000, 201810020):
    ID = UID
    print(ID)
    
    ZeroDay = s.post("https://site/Add_StudantRow.php", data={"SID":ID})
    ZeroDay_content = bs(ZeroDay.content, "html.parser", from_encoding='windows-1256')
    
    if ZeroDay_content.find("form", <xxxxxxx>):
        std_ID    = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"SID[]"})["value"]
        std_name  = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"Name[]"})["value"]
        std_major_= ZeroDay_content.select_one("option[selected]", {"name":"Qualifications[]"})["value"]
        std_major = ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"Specialization[]"})["value"]
        std_social= ZeroDay_content.select_one("select[name='MILITARY_STATUS[]'] option[selected]")["value"]
        std_ID_num= ZeroDay_content.find("input", {"name":"ID_Number[]"})["value"]
        std_gender= ZeroDay_content.select_one("select[name='Gender[]'] option[selected]")["value"]
        
        print(std_ID, std_name, std_gender, std_major, std_major_, std_ID_num,s td_social)
```

Where `<xxxxx>` would be suitable attributes to search for.

The error you are getting is because your first `.find()` call is returning `None` to indicate that the item is not present. You then use `["value"]` on `None` which gives the error without first testing if you have found the required item.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve this by add an IF statement and use content-length as a thing to determine that the request was made or not, because i have noticed that the content-length is less than 170 if the request is return nothing and more 170 if return any thing .

Comment: Dependending on content-length for this is asking for a problem, see Martin's answer